# Get state output port formatting

Tags: drake

For Multibodyplant,
we have this function: https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html#ad4e8834bd252d1265e99b8ac85fad0b5

1. Are the positions all concatenated first, then the velocities, when we have multiple bodies?
2. Suppose we are adding multiple objects to the rigid body 1 by 1 with:

   body = plant.AddRigidBody(
   name, instance,
   SpatialInertia(mass=mass,
   p_PScm_E=np.array([0., 0., 0.]),
   G_SP_E=inertia))

How do I then find the section of the get_state_output_port() vector that corresponds to a given "body" from my object adding stage?

3. Is there any way to look at the vector output of get_state_output_port(), and see exactly what each object each part of the state is, or a helper function to see what each index of the state is, i.e. what object that index is associated with, what variable (like maybe a string saying this is theta_double_dot)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`MultibodyPlant::GetStateNames()`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html#a46a5af92839fb703ff1c299ddbadce04) and the related `GetPositionNames()`, `GetVelocityNames()`, `GetActuatorNames()` methods to help you introspect the string names/values of the elements of those vectors.

If you're in Python, you can use these with `namedview` to help set/get the individual elements by name.  For instance, I use this pretty heavily in [this notebook for trajectory optimization on a quadruped](https://deepnote.com/workspace/Underactuated-2ed1518a-973b-4145-bd62-1768b49956a8/project/05-Highly-articulated-Legged-Robots-a0b741c1-31ed-480b-992f-b4307d227e58/notebook/littledog-f424e54c6317431099240b8d58f80d8a).

```
    PositionView = namedview(
        "Positions",
        plant.GetPositionNames(
            plant.GetModelInstanceByName("LittleDog"), always_add_suffix=False
        ),
    )
    hip_roll = 0.1
    hip_pitch = 1
    knee = 1.55
    q0 = PositionView.Zero()
    q0.front_right_hip_roll = -hip_roll
    q0.front_right_hip_pitch = hip_pitch
    q0.front_right_knee = -knee
    q0.front_left_hip_roll = hip_roll
    q0.front_left_hip_pitch = hip_pitch
    q0.front_left_knee = -knee
    q0.back_right_hip_roll = -hip_roll
    q0.back_right_hip_pitch = -hip_pitch
    q0.back_right_knee = knee
    q0.back_left_hip_roll = hip_roll
    q0.back_left_hip_pitch = -hip_pitch
    q0.back_left_knee = knee
    q0._world_body_qw = 1.0  # Unit quaternion
    q0._world_body_z = 0.146
    plant.SetPositions(context, q0[:])
```

Comment: GetStateNames is nowhere to be found in MultibodyPlant as a static method or in an instance of MultibodyPlant. Can you confirm this function exists in Python?

Comment: You probably need to update Drake.  It should be available in the v1.15.0 release.  (the python code that I shared uses it, so clearly it exists in python).